# obtaining weighted centroids using regionprops in matlab + jacket

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gpu, jacket

Using Matlab's image processing toolbox I can find weighted centroids using the [`regionprops` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html). This is because the function can return either a  `WeightedCentroid` or a list of pixels indices per labeled part of the image, by `PixelList`, and then the weighted centroid is easily calculated. However, [jacket's support in regionprops](http://wiki.accelereyes.com/wiki/index.php/Regionprops) only returns an unweighted centroid (or the centroid of the binary "island" that was obtained using `bwlabel` earlier). This means that the info regarding pixel positions was somehow used in order to find these centroids.

How can I access jacket's regionprops info regarding the list of pixels it uses to calculate the unweighted centroid so I could use it to calculate a weighted centroid?
(One important reason to do this is because the function `find` cannot be used in a `gfor` loop, otherwise one can `find` the different output values of `bwlabel`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested performance, but here is an algorithm to get weighted centroids and areas.
This should work with Jacket as well as matlab (depending on the type of Input).

```
function [WC, WA] = WeightedMoments(L, I);
  [m, n] = size(L);
  [keys, idx] = sort(L(:));

  % Get weights and locations in sorted order
  w = I(idx);
  idx = idx - 1; % Convert to 0-index for simplicity
  x = floor(idx / m);
  y = idx - x * m;

  % Location of the starting point of each region.
  locs = find([diff(keys); 1]);

  % Weighted area and locations
  Msum = cumsum([w, x.*w, y.*w]);
  Mloc = diff(Msum(locs,:));
  M00 = Mloc(:, 1);
  M10 = Mloc(:, 2);
  M01 = Mloc(:, 3);

  % Weighted centroids and areas
  WC = [M10 ./ M00, M01 ./ M00] + 1; % Convert back to 1-index
  WA = M00;
end
```

P.S. I am a developer at AccelerEyes. Sorry about the delay.

**EDIT**: Cleaned up the code a little bit.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed takes some toll in performance, but it does the job.

Comment: I'm trying to improve the efficiency of this code, and I was wandering how hard would it be "mex" it (for jacket-cuda)? From your experience, how much faster would a mex version of this be?